# Is there any verse in Vedas explaining Instantaneous Action at a distance

Tags: vedas, philosophy, science, vedic-gods

I'm a Theoretical physicist rather than that I am a Hindu.These days, I'm on my research on Quantum Entanglement.
This simply says that "An event at one place can instantaneously event at another place arbitrarily far away faster than light"
On my quest on my research I saw this verse in Vishnu Sahasthranama sthrothram
"Manojavasthīrthãkarō vãsurethah vãsuprãdhã|
Vãsuprãdho va:sudhevo vasurvasumana: havihi ||"

The term Manojavah is explained as siddhi with which we can travel or teleport faster than light.
Please anyone list out verses in Vedas that allows entanglement and teleportation and how Vedas explain these processes in cosmos.
I'll be thankful.

Comment: Read 'Raja Yoga' (which includes Vivekananda's translation of Patanjali's Yoga Sutras). Available here -   http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_1/vol_1_frame.htm I am not aware of anything in the Vedas themselves, but there are some things in secondary texts. Start with the reference above.

Comment: The term Manojavah means "Speed like wind" . see here -http://www.bachpan.com/Meaning-of-Manojavam.aspx , and not as faster than light .obviously we cant teleport ourselves with speed like wind.

Answer (score 2):

Finding a direct mention of a modern day scientific theory in texts that are over 5000 years old, would be an exercise in futility.

It is the implied evidence hidden in deep symbolism that can let us assume that the ancient sages new a lot about the creation & working of the universe to a fairly accurate degree.

As per Wikipedia,

> [Quantum Entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) is a physical phenomenon that occurs when
>   pairs or groups of particles are generated or interact in ways such
>   that the quantum state of each particle cannot be described
>   independently of the others...

Or to put in the simple terms.

> Even the farthest points in the cosmos are related and respond to each
>   other through ‘something’

**Here's what Manu Smriti has to say.**

[image]

1.27 But with the minute perishable particles of the five (elements) which have been mentioned, this whole(world) is framed in due order.

```
This sloka in it’s core talks about the same fundamental sub-atomic elements 
being the building blocks of everything in the known universe.
```

[image]

1.20 Among them each succeeding (element) acquires the quality of the preceding one, and whatever place (in the sequence) each of them occupies, even so many qualities it is declared to possess.

```
This sloka mentions that since everything is made from the same basic elements, 
they also have the qualities of each other.
```

[image]

1.26. Moreover, in order to distinguish actions, he separated merit from demerit, and he caused the creatures to be affected by the pairs (of opposites), such as pain and pleasure.

```
And here is the symbolism for inherent duality in nature that quantum mechanics advocates.
```

**Coming to the relation part...**

[image]

1.50. The (various) conditions in this always terrible and constantly changing circle of births and deaths to which created beings are subject, are stated to begin with (that of) Brahman, and to end with (that of) these (just mentioned immovable creatures).

```
Einstein called it Ether, Particle Physics calls it Higgs Field  
And Quantum Mechanics calls it Entanglement
```

**In Hinduism it is ‘Brahman’ or ‘Consciousness’**

‘Brahman’ is the force behind creation and reason behind entanglement of everything in the universe.

Reference: [Manu Smriti](https://www.scribd.com/doc/7189037/Manu-Smriti-Sanskrit-Text-With-English-Translation)

Comment: and 1.20 you mentioned can be explained in terms of Quantum mechanics as "A particle exists partly in all of its possible states possible" That's marvel....and this proves me that physics is nothing but applied Vedic philosophy..

Comment: Can u ellobarately explain the sloka 1.50

Comment: @SrikanthReddy, I am glad i could help. Taking just one answer as conclusive evidence of physics being entirely derived from Vedic philosophy would be biased. I am adding the resource link to the answer for further reading.

Comment: @WeShall...No.I have just done it logically... :)